# How to create a good primary key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I have an application on AWS using DynamoDB with user sending messages to each other. I am not familiar with AWS and I am lacking best practice knowledge.

My application has now started to get slow to retrieve messages for a user because I have more and more data in my database.

I am thinking that it is because of my primary key and I wonder what could be a good primary key in this case.

Currently I am using a random guid as a primary key.

I am looking to retrieve all messages corresponding to a user, I am using a scan operation for this.

I would like to use a composite value based on username as a primary key but I wonder if it will be better. For instance, if I need to retrieve the number of messages for a user and to increment it will probably be even longer to do the request to create the primary key.

What would be a good primary key here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a scan or query operation on your table?

Comment: I am scanning the table to retrieve all messages of a user

Comment: you should never ever do a scan of table for user queries. for starting up with schema design have a look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-a-serverless-real-time-chat-application-with-aws-appsync/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be better since it appears you often query based on the userid.  Scans are expensive and should be avoided where possible.  AWS has a [great article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) on best practices for choosing a partition key (primary key).  The key takeaway is the following:

1. You should evaluate various approaches based on your data ingestion and **access pattern**, then choose the most appropriate key with the least probability of hitting throttling issues.
2. Using a guid for the partition/primary key is a waste if you never query the data using it.  Since using the query operation (rather than using scan) requires querying using the partition/primary (and sort key), you want to ensure you choose a value that you use to retrieve the data often and also has the sufficient cardinality to ensure your data is distributed across a reasonable amount of partitions.

What other access patterns do you have in your application? From what you've mentioned so far, userid seems to be a reasonable choice.

Comment: Thanks! What is the best way to build a composite value from userid according to you ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a composite value?  And do you only have one item in the table per user?

Comment: Question still stands though, why the requirement for a composite key?

Comment: I though using the username in my primary key would faster the scan compared to using a random guid

Comment: It will be and that's what I'm suggesting, but that is not the same thing as a composite key.  A composite key is when you use an attribute for the primary key and another attribute for the sort key.  The sort key is used to order the entries that hash to the same DDB partition table.  Pick another attribute for the sort key that you typically filter on also, or if not, define just the primary/partition key as username.

Comment: Thanks yes I can’t use username for primary key because I have many messages for a same user. So I guess I will need to use username + guid for instance ?

Comment: Yup, if there is nothing else that can provide uniqueness, then use the username for the partition key and guid for the sort key. But if you have another field which combined with the username can provide uniqueness, then use that as the sort key and username as the primary key.